# Do I have a PS Plus subscription?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

So I recently ordered a PS4 on Gamestop's website. I ordered a PS4 and a year-long subscription to Sony's Playstation Plus. I used the code on my account, but the purchase didn't go through because I had just moved and the credit cards had the wrong address. We called customer service and they re-did the purchase yesterday. However, I am not sure if I have a valid PS Plus subscription. You can see my confusion in these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

It says I have a subscription, but it also says I don't have time remaining on it. My PSN name is 'ZachTehReaper' (I very much want to change this, which is part of why I am making asking for help), if that helps.

Was my PSN subscription purchase valid?

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is, it says you have access from 8/20/2016 to 8/20/2017

Comment: It seems your subscription is valid until 2017, that's (almost) 1 year from now. By the way: This isn't a PSN (PlayStation Network) subscription, it's a PS+ (PlayStation Plus) one.

Answer (score 2):

Login to your account on your console. You should see a small golden plus icon next to your profile. (It's been a while for me so might be wrong here.)

As an alternative, go to the PlayStation Store and look for the PS Plus category. You should see a few games that are free for subscribers. Buy one. (You can keep these forever, but they're only accessible with an active subscription. The selection changes monthly.)

Comment: Unfortunetly I can only access the website but this is a screenshot of my name https://gyazo.com/26744bada064faef84a80e9786b08a10

Comment: @ZachS. That "Join PS Plus" link shouldn't be there. You can try the shop in your browser: https://store.playstation.com/

Comment: @ZachS. Just looked you up, and the PS Plus icon doesn't appear next to your name like it does for other people (on my console, at least).

Comment: @pushasha So i don't have it?

Comment: @ZachS. I don't think so, man. I see other people  in the list with the icon next to their names when I start looking your username up, and then when I finish my search, your name is the only one in the list -- without the icon. Sounds like it may be time to contact support again.